# Max-flow/Min-cut theorem from perfect graphs?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

A number of min/max results in combinatorics are closely related to the perfection of various kinds of graphs. König's theorem follows from the fact that the complements of bipartite graphs are perfect, and Dilworth's theorem and Mirsky's theorem involve the perfection of comparability graphs and their complements.

All three of the above theorems are related to the max-flow/min-cut theorem, and in many algorithms classes these theorems are proved algorithmkcally using network flows in appropriately-constructed graphs.

My question is whether there is some way of reframing the max flow or min cut problems in a way that involves forming some sort of perfect graph along the lines of the three above theorems. I did some searching around and didn't find anything on this topic, and I'm curious primarily because this would provide a really neat unified picture of all these min/max type results.